# Getting FILENAME in awk for multiple compressed files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, filenames

I am trying to run a command on multiple files that would print the row if the first column is equal to “aaa” or is equal to “bbb” *and* add a column before that with the name of the file.

Sample file (sample.tsv.gz):

```
aaa, 111, 222
bbb, 333, 444
ccc, 555, 666
```

I want the output to be:

```
sample.tsv.gz, aaa, 111, 222
sample.tsv.gz, bbb, 333, 444
```

My command is:

```
zcat *.tsv.gz | awk '{if ($1==“aaa”||$1==“bbb”) {print FILENAME (NF?",":"") $0}}'
```

The output I get is:

```
-, aaa, 111, 222
-, bbb, 333, 444
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `-` means stdin in the output, that's what you are using as input, not a real file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is parsing `stdin` provided by the output of your previous command, so filename is not available. One way to deal with it is this:

```
for f in *.tsv.gz; do
    zcat "$f" | awk -F, -v f="$f" '$1=="aaa" || $1=="bbb"{print f (NF?", ":"") $0}'
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, `find` + `xargs` + `awk` solution.

```
find *.gz -print0 | 
xargs -0 -I fname sh -c 'gzip -dc fname | awk -v file="fname" -f prog.awk'
```

Where `prog.awk` program file should have following contents, this takes care of OP's condition of checking if first line's 1st is `aaa` or 2nd field is `bbb`.

```
cat prog.awk
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
{
 if($1=="aaa" || $1=="bbb"){
   print file,$0
 }
}
```

---

---

***Testing of above solution:***

1. Let's create a test Input_file with name `file` as follows:
2. Create its `gzip -k Input_file`
3. Check if we could read its contents or not by doing `gzip -dc file1.gz`
4. Finally run command mentioned above to check if its working fine or not.

---

```
##1st step
cat file1
aaa,bbb,ccc

##2nd step
gzip -k file1

##3rd step
gzip -dc file1.gz
aaa,bbb,ccc

##Execute solution:
find *.gz -print0 |
> xargs -0 -I fname sh -c 'gzip -dc fname | awk -v file="fname" -f prog.awk'
 Input_file.gz,aaa,bbb,ccc
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk (v.3) that runs the `zcat` within:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=", "                          # delimiter in the sample data

    for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++) {                # iterating the argument files
        zcat="zcat " ARGV[i]             # zcat command
        while((zcat | getline)>0)        # process while data left
            if ($1=="aaa"||$1=="bbb") {
                print ARGV[i], $0
            }
    }
}' *.gz
```

Output with two copies of your data:

```
bar.gz, aaa, 111, 222
bar.gz, bbb, 333, 444
foo.gz, aaa, 111, 222
foo.gz, bbb, 333, 444
```